# How does one register a Loki Network Name on the Loki name service?

Tags: monero-forks, loki, loki-name-service

I want to register a lns loki name service name on the loki network. How do I do this via the command line? And what is the cost of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register using the command:

```
lns_buy_mapping namehere 0000...1111
```

You link the name to a session chat id or a loki address.

To check if you own it do:

```
lns_print_owners_to_names
```

Cost is currently 20 loki.